# passing data from service to a controller in angular

Tags: angularjs, google-api

I am having a small issue sending data from service to a controller with google API. can anyone have a look at code below and give me some advice?
injection is good and I don't see any errors. I tried few things. 
1. normal binding using a service method(e.g. getCurrentPos()). it will return an object that stores the pos info
2. $rootScope.$broadcast
3. angular.copy()

```
//in the service--------
var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);

this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map,
    title: markers[i][0],
    draggable: true,
    icon: '../img/png/shopper1.png'
});
var personMarker = this.marker;
this.marker.addListener('drag', function() {
  console.log('lat:'+personMarker.getPosition().lat()+' lng:'+personMarker.getPosition().lng());
  currentPos.lat = personMarker.getPosition().lat();
  currentPos.lng = personMarker.getPosition().lng();
  // myPos = personMarker.getPosition();
  myPos = [personMarker.getPosition().lat(), personMarker.getPosition().lng()];
  angular.copy(myPos, scope.currentPos); //not working
  console.log('scope.currentPos',scope.currentPos);
  // $rootScope.$broadcast('evtUpdateMyPos', { //tried but not working.
  //   'lat': personMarker.getPosition().lat(),
  //   'lng': personMarker.getPosition().lng()
  // });
  console.log("mypos:", myPos);

});

//in the controller-------
$scope.currentPos = [];
//Listen on a broadcast event
// $scope.$on('evtUpdateMyPos', function (event, myPos){
//   console.log('evtUpdateMyPos is fired.', myPos); //this logs here.
//   // $scope.currentPos = angular.copy(myPos); //this dos not help
//   // $scope.currentPos = myPos; //this does not hlep.

// })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases when you're trying to update your model from an external library like in your case using google maps you should wrap the setter in something like this:

```
$timeout(function(){
   myModel = 'Google.map.data'
});
```

or

```
$rootScope.$applyAsync(function(){ // this could also be $scope
   myModel = 'Google.map.data'
});
```

`myModel` could be a property of your service or a $scope variable ($scope.myModel)

Comment: thank you a lot. was able to solve it with your advice.